# Parse error with nested IFs in an array formula using SUMPRODUCT and VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a nested IF formula to calculate the value of a VLOOKUP-ed range of cells in a separate spreadsheet using `if`, `arrayformula`, `sumproduct`, `vlookup`, and `importrange`. There are three possible results in the nested if, based on the  value of cell F3 (blank, "bar", and "foo"). Here's the code I have so far:

```
=if(isblank(F3), "",
if(F3="bar", 
ArrayFormula(sumproduct(vlookup(A3, importrange("external link", "Form Responses 1!D:BA"),{2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40},0))), 
if(F3="foo", ArrayFormula(sumproduct(vlookup(H3, importrange("external link", "Form Responses 1!D:BA"){2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40},0))))))
```

(`bar` and `foo` determine the cell VLOOKUP uses as a search key).

The array formula works fine by itself, it is only when I start adding any IFs that the output becomes `"#ERROR!"` (formula parse error).

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to integrate this nested if and array formula?

Answer (score 2):

Your first `vlookup` looks like

```
vlookup(something, importrange(blah, blah) , {2,4,6,…,40}, 0)
```

but your second one looks like

```
vlookup(something, importrange(blah, blah)   {2,4,6,…,40}, 0)
```

i.e., it appears to be missing a comma before the `{`.

---

P.S. You can simplify that horribly long formula by using

```
if(F3="bar", A3, if(F3="foo", H3, <something_else>))
```

as in

```
vlookup(
       if(F3="bar", A3, if(F3="foo", H3, <whatever>)) ,
                                                     importrange(blah, blah),{2,4,6,…,40},0)
```

instead of
repeating the `ArrayFormula(sumproduct(vlookup(…)))` expression twice.